# Trying to serve spring boot and react js from two endpoints

Tags: reactjs, maven, spring-boot, webpack

I want to build a Spring Boot CRUD application that has a REST API(backend) and a React/JS app(frontend). The structure of my application is essientially a multi-module Maven application which is shown below: [image: Application structure]. I want to serve the REST API at localhost:5000 and the React/JS app at localhost:8080. I was following these tutorials, [here](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/11/08/a-minimalist-guide-to-building-spring-boot-angular-5-applications/), [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setup-a-react-environment-using-webpack-and-babel), [here](http://justincalleja.com/2016/04/17/serving-a-webpack-bundle-in-spring-boot/), [here](https://medium.com/@drgenejones/proxying-an-external-api-with-webpack-serve-code-and-a-restful-data-from-separate-endpoints-4da9b8daf430). The code is as below:

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
})
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        /**'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',**/
        path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'index.js')
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map', 
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        /**publicPath: '/assets/',**/
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 8080,
        hot: true,
        proxy: {
        '/api/*': {
            target: 'http://localhost:5000',
            secure: false
        }
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['babel-loader'], include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')},
        {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css'], include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

### Ubgrill/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ubgrill</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>frontend</module>
        <module>backend</module>
    </modules>

    <name>Ubgrill</name>
    <description>A CRUD application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

### Ubgrill/frontend/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>Ubgrill</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <node.version>v8.9.0</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.3.2</yarn.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and yarn</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>yarn install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>yarn build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Ubgrill/backend/pom.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>Ubgrill</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Ubgrill/frontend/app/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

### Ubgrill/frontend/app/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>React App Setup</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Ubgrill/frontend/app/components/App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>);
        }
}
```

When I run `yarn start` in the frontend folder and I go to the browser at localhost:8080, I do not get any output but in the terminal, I get[image: Output from terminal] . My question is **how I correct this?**. Thanks.

Comment: did you try localhost:8080/index.html ?

Comment: @brub Just tried it. It does not output the phrase "Hello World".